# Wordpress Installation page displays after migration from expired MAMP Pro Trial to Free Version of MAMP (OSX)

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, phpmyadmin, mamp

I decided to learn how to create a word press site on my local machine and installed "MAMP" for OSX. when installing mamp i also installed a trial of MAMP PRO and began development.

I have now come to the point where the MAMP PRO trial has expired, meaning I can no longer continue development on my site until I migrate to the free version of MAMP. I was told by the people behind MAMP that this would be a seamless process once the trial expired but I have quickly found that that is not the case.

So far I have completed the following steps and am still unable to access my Wordpress site, instead, when I navigate to the site, I am presented with the installation screen.

1. Copied my Wordpress mySQL database folder from:

**/Library/Application Support/appsolute/MAMP PRO/db/mysql/**

To

**/Applications/MAMP/db/mysql/**

2. Then I updated my sites wp-config file to the following:
   [image: wp-config screen]

note that this file lives in:

/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/wordpress/

...It was at this point where I attempted to hit my Worpress site and was presented with the installation screen. So I then took an additional step and attempted to restore MySQL to its original settings, via the following tutorial:

http://www.tech-otaku.com/local-server/resetting-mamp-mysql-root-user-password/

And then:

http://www.tech-otaku.com/local-server/changing-mysql-root-user-password-mamp/#mamp-files-to-update

Additional Info:

I am able to see the site's database when I look at phpMyAdmin after starting MAMP (free version):

[image: phpMyAdmin screenshot]

I have given full privileges to the root user on my db (I wasn't sure if this was necessary):

[image: privs]

After doing all of this I STILL get redirected to the install screen when I navigate to

http://localhost:8888/wordpress

[image: install page]

EDIT:

I just saw this which was strange, it says there are no tables in my DB, yet I can see them on the left hand side:

[image: myadmin no tables]

Answer (score 0):

First, go to http:/localhost/phpmyadmin/.
There should be your old database which you were using in MAMP Pro.

Click on the database and in the top you'll find a button labeled 'Export'. Hit that one and hit 'Start' at the bottom of the page. A .sql file will be downloaded.

Now go to your new database which you want to use in MAMP or create a new one.
If you choose to use the one you already created click on the database and select all the rows and click on delete, so your database will be empty.

Click on the new database and in the top you'll find a button labeled 'Import'. Hit that one and upload the .sql file that you downloaded just a moment ago. Hit 'Start' on the bottom of the page and it will be fixed.

Comment: Unfortunately, because MAMP Pro is expired, I cannot start it up and access phpMyAdmin, I can only access phpMyAdmin for the free version.